# SQL selección de todos los pedidos de clientes que incluyan uno en concreto

Tags: sql, ms-access

A ver si me podéis ayudar con una consulta que se me está resistiendo. Necesito sacar todos los pedidos de todos los clientes pero sólo de aquellos clientes que hayan pedido bicicletas. Es decir, si un cliente tiene en la tabla relacionada de pedidos cinco conceptos distintos y entre ellos está bicicletas que los muestre todos, pero si no están las bicicletas que no muestre ningún pedido.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Gracias.

Edito, me faltaban muchos datos. Es en access, típica tabla clientes con dni de clave principal. Otra tabla de pedidos con el dni relacionado y los distintos productos pedidos. Tengo claro el select para que salgan las bicicletas, pero lo que necesito es que salgan todos los demás pedidos si pidió bicicletas.
He estado investigando y me inclino por una subconsulta, algo así como:

```
SELECT pedidos FROM tablaPedidos WHERE pedidos IN 
(SELECT pedidos FROM tablaPedidos where pedidos="bicicletas")
```

Pero no termina de salirme.

Sigo investigando, no van por ahí los tiros, parece. Veo algo con la cláusula EXISTS en algún tipo de consulta anidada. Sigo probando.

Comment: Muestra la estructura de las tablas, datos de ejemplo, el resultado esperado y el resultado obtenido en base a la consulta que has intentado. Además, ¿qué motor de base de datos es? Lee [ask] y [los ingredientes de una buena pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433).

Answer (score 1):

Ibas bien, sólo te has liado con el `dni`, que es el dato que necesitas para quedarte con los pedidos de los clientes que te interesan:

```
SELECT * FROM tablaPedidos WHERE dni IN (
    SELECT tablaPedidos.dni
    FROM tablaPedidos
    WHERE tablaPedidos.pedidos="bicicletas"
);
```

Fíjate en que `pedidos` es el dato que ya tienes desde el principio.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que pude entender lo que necesitas es relacionar dos tablas cuyos datos coincidan, por lo cual es probable que lo que necesites sea un
[INNER JOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/operaci%C3%B3n-inner-join-b9e73ab6-884a-403e-9f22-cb502feae36a).

```
SELECT Clientes.DNI, Pedidos.Pedido
FROM Clientes INNER JOIN Pedidos
ON Clientes.DNI = Pedidos.DNI;
```

En el ejemplo relacionas las dos tablas por el DNI, suponiendo que tienes una estructura similar devolvería los datos de las tablas Clientes y Pedidos donde compartan el mismo "DNI".